Mysql query to get difference % comparing week over week
I need a script to get the % difference comparing the data week over week. I have already a script that works well for all weeks except for the actual week.
The problem I have is that for the current week I want to compare only the completed days, for example if today is Wednesday I want to compare Monday + Tuesday this week over Monday + Tuesday last week. My script is comparing Monday+Tuesday this week over the whole last week.
This is the output I need:



WeekNum
Year
%Orders Difference
%NC difference




20
2024
30.47%
30.56%


19
2024
29.96%
32.20%


18
2024
32.08%
31.29%



This is my actual script:
WITH CTE AS ( 
  SELECT  
        week(purchased_est,1) as weeknum, 
        year(purchased_est) as yearsales,  
        count(*) as TotalOrders , 
    IFNULL(SUM(net_comp),0) as NCTotal
   FROM revenue
   WHERE purchased_est < @today 
   GROUP by week(purchased_est,1), YEAR(purchased_est)
   order by YEAR(purchased_est) desc,  week(purchased_est,1) desc
)
SELECT
  CTE.weeknum, 
  CTE.yearsales, 
  CONCAT(ROUND((CTE.TotalOrders -  LEAD(CTE.TotalOrders) OVER (ORDER BY CTE.yearsales desc, CTE.weeknum desc))/ LEAD(CTE.TotalOrders) OVER (ORDER BY CTE.yearsales desc, CTE.weeknum desc) *100,2),'%') as 'Orders difference',
  CONCAT(ROUND((CTE.NCTotal -  LEAD(CTE.NCTotal) OVER (ORDER BY CTE.yearsales desc, CTE.weeknum desc))/ LEAD(CTE.NCTotal) OVER (ORDER BY CTE.yearsales desc, CTE.weeknum desc) *100,2),'%') as 'NC difference'
FROM CTE

THE CTE output is:
enter image description here
This script doesn't do the math correctly for the current week it is comparing the completed days this week (days before today) over the whole last week.
Please help me!

The expected output is excellent, but we also need the simple data. Please provide the simple data as well

You need a UNION ALL of two queries. One that gets you all past weeks with their totals compared to their previous week's totals. And one that gets you the current week with its totals compared to the same days last week.

As suggested by Thorsten Kettner in the comments:

You need a UNION ALL of two queries. One that gets you all past weeks with their totals compared to their previous week's totals. And one that gets you the current week with its totals compared to the same days last week.

Here I have combined the aggregation and window function steps, but I have included the separated versions in this db<>fiddle. The data is junk but it is enough to do some basic checks on the output of the queries.
WITH before_this_week_with_prev AS ( 
    SELECT  
        YEAR(purchased_est) AS year_sales,
        WEEK(purchased_est, 1) AS week_num,
        COUNT(*) AS total_orders,
        IFNULL(SUM(net_comp), 0) AS total_nc,
        LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER w AS prev_orders,
        LAG(IFNULL(SUM(net_comp), 0)) OVER w AS prev_nc
    FROM revenue
    WHERE purchased_est < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY
    GROUP BY YEAR(purchased_est), WEEK(purchased_est, 1)
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY YEAR(purchased_est), WEEK(purchased_est, 1))
),
this_week_and_last_with_prev AS ( 
    SELECT  
        YEAR(purchased_est) AS year_sales,
        WEEK(purchased_est, 1) AS week_num, 
        SUM(WEEKDAY(purchased_est) < WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) AS total_orders,
        IFNULL(SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(purchased_est) < WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE), net_comp, 0)), 0) AS total_nc,
        LAG(SUM(WEEKDAY(purchased_est) < WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE))) OVER w AS prev_orders,
        LAG(IFNULL(SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(purchased_est) < WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE), net_comp, 0)), 0)) OVER w AS prev_nc
    FROM revenue
    WHERE purchased_est < CURRENT_DATE
    AND purchased_est >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) + 7) DAY
    GROUP BY YEAR(purchased_est), WEEK(purchased_est, 1)
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY YEAR(purchased_est), WEEK(purchased_est, 1))
),
all_with_prev AS (
    SELECT * FROM before_this_week_with_prev
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM this_week_and_last_with_prev WHERE week_num = WEEK(CURRENT_DATE, 1)
)

SELECT
    week_num, 
    year_sales,
    total_orders,
    prev_orders,
    total_nc,
    prev_nc,
    CONCAT(ROUND(((total_orders / prev_orders) - 1) * 100, 2), '%') AS 'Orders difference',
    CONCAT(ROUND(((total_nc / prev_nc) - 1) * 100, 2), '%') AS 'NC difference'
FROM all_with_prev
ORDER BY year_sales DESC, week_num DESC;

